# What happens if I log in the day after my Pokemon gets kicked out of a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Let's say I have two Pokemon in two different gyms. One of them gets kicked out and I get the max 50 pokecoins for that day. But then after I close the app the other one gets kicked out.

If I signed in the next day would I earn pokecoins? Or would the game not give me them since they got kicked out the previous day?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will **not** get multiple times 50 coins. The coin-getting is calculated server-side (and therefor the coins are determined immediately when you are kicked out), so it does not depend if you are online or not.